# Dynamics 365 CE On Premises, Asynch Service is crashing with SQL Exception related to Datacenter object not found in DB

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamic365, dynamics-365-ce, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

On one of Client we have Dynamics 365 CE On Premises V 9.0.4xxx.
Environment is Development, single CRM server installation having claim based authentication using ADFS. Database and Reporting Services is on another server.

We are facing some performance issues, when we investigated we found that CRM Async Service is getting crashed with the last message which says that

"The locator service failed to connect to the configuration database (MSCRM_CONFIG). The error was: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Datacenter'."

We enabled the CRM Trace Logs and found that Asynch Service is trying to query in the database against Datacenter object which is not to be found. We investigated on many other environments and this table, view or synonym is not to be found in any of the instances. Searched on Internet and though many users faced this issue but didn't found any solution. As a last resort from our end we are in process to move to latest release of Dynamics 365 CE which is 9.1.3.11 in hope if that is a product issue, it might already solved.

If anyone have faced the same issue and/or have a solution, it would be appreciated. Thanks

**Complete error msg.**

```
The locator service failed to connect to the configuration database (MSCRM_CONFIG). The error was: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Datacenter'. 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.InternalExecuteWithRetry[TResult](Func`1 ExecuteMethod, IDbCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.<>c_DisplayClass104_0.<InternalExecuteReader>b_0()
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.InternalExecuteReader(IDbCommand command, Nullable`1 commandBehavior, Int32 sourceLineNumber, String memberName, String sourceFilePath)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand command, Boolean impersonate, Int32 sourceLineNumber, String memberName, String sourceFilePath)
   at Microsoft.Crm.SharedDatabase.DatabaseService.ExecuteBaseReader(CrmDbConnection connection, IDbCommand command, String[] columns, IDictionary collectionToFill)
ClientConnectionId:ef125c05-864e-4598-8ba5-c3f71bad613e
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16.
```

**Error in Dynamics 365 CE Trace Log**

[image: Error in Dynamics 365 CE Trace Log]

Comment: Odd, seems to be a remnant of the Online version of Dynamics. Did you solve this issue or did you just upgrade to the latest version?